# add a delay ON fadeTo() jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below:

```
  $('.pic').fadeIn("slow"); // attempt calling twice
  $('.pic').fadeTo("slow", 0.8);
```

I would like to show the pic for about 1 second before the `fadeTo` occurs. Currently it just shows the pic with the `fadeTo` there when JS runs.

I have tried incorporating delays in both.

```
  $('.pic').delay(1000).fadeTo("slow", 0.8);
```

The above just delayed in showing the whole pic. Did not delay the `fadeTo`. Again **my goal is to show the pic normal for 1 second and *THEN* *fadeTo* occurs.**

**Revise / Update:**

So, with the answers below I'm still not getting desired result. Desired result again, is to show the image normal, with full opacity. For 1 second, before `fadeTo` occurs. Same problem is occurring with the below suggestions. It's just setting a `.delay` before it shows. It's not allowing animation to have full opacity and show normal for one second and then `fadeTo`.

Comment: It seems you forgot to call `fadeIn` in your second example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chain the functions, so you can use [`delay`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/):

```
$('.pic').fadeIn("slow").delay(1000).fadeTo("slow", 0.8);
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dk0fupzt/)